# How to fill an array with a for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I’m having a lot of trouble learning how to use `for` loops to fill a new variable. As an example say if I have `var year = [2010, 2000, 1992];` and `var age = [];`.

How would I use a `for` loop to fill in the age variable?

If this is a bad example, don’t use this. I just would like some help with understanding how to fill in empty arrays.

```js
var names = ["Ace", "yoshi", "Lassie"];
var age = [25, 23, 5];
var u24 = [];
for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
  if ([age] < 24) {
    u24 += age[i]
    console.log("hello " + names + " " + "you are" + age);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please check this code and try yourself, 
You can use forEach functions and inside loop function you just subtract year with current year and store.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_forEach.asp

Comment: Do you expect `[age]` to be a single number to be compared with `24`? Are you familiar with the `Array` `filter` and `push` functions?

Comment: if i understand correctly then instead of `u24 += age[i]`you can use `u24[] = age[i]` or `u24.push(age[i])`

Comment: @keja No, you cannot use `u24[] = age[i]`.

Comment: @Xufox you are right, dont know what i was thinking :D prob not thinking..

Comment: Thank you for all your help everyone in this set of  comments as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to create objects that contain relevant data. Combining the `name` and `age` into a person object would help.

```js
var persons = [
  {
    name: "Ace",
    age: 25
  },
  {
    name: "yoshi",
    age: 23
  },
  {
    name: "Lassie",
    age: 5
  }
];
var u24=[];
for (var i =0; i < persons.length; i++) {
  var person = persons[i];
 if(person.age < 24){
  u24.push(person.age);
  console.log("hello " + person.name + " " + "you are " + person.age);
 }
}
console.log(u24);
```

But you can also use `forEach` like this:

```js
var persons = [
  {
    name: "Ace",
    age: 25
  },
  {
    name: "yoshi",
    age: 23
  },
  {
    name: "Lassie",
    age: 5
  }
];
var u24=[];
persons.forEach(
  function(person) {
    if(person.age < 24){
      u24.push(person.age);
      console.log("hello " + person.name + " " + "you are " + person.age);
    }
  }
);
console.log(u24);
```

By making objects that include all relevant data your loops will never get out of sync. If you remove a person from the `persons` array then their `name` and `age` will go together.

UPDATE: Using a filter

```js
var persons = [
  {
    name: "Ace",
    age: 25
  },
  {
    name: "yoshi",
    age: 23
  },
  {
    name: "Lassie",
    age: 5
  }
];

var youngPersons = persons.filter(
  function(person) {
    return (person.age < 24);
  }
);

console.log(youngPersons);
```

Or using an ES6 Arrow Function

```js
    var persons = [
      { name: "Ace", age: 25 },
      { name: "yoshi", age: 23 },
      { name: "Lassie", age: 5 }
    ];

    var youngPersons = persons.filter((person) => person.age < 24);

    console.log(youngPersons);
```

This provides back an array of the persons that match your `Age under 24` criteria.

Comment: Just use `filter` instead of `forEach`.

Comment: Yes, `filter` can work if you are just trying to get a filtered list. Since @Ace didn't post what his intent was I may have assumed a different intent.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Quick question and it may be a dumb question but what is another way of putting the new information in to u24 beside using push. As in  would it be u24 =person.age?

Comment: You set up `u24` as an array. So I assumed you wanted an array of ages.

Comment: @intervalia I do

Comment: Do you just want ages or, like in my newer examples, do you want the combination of ages and names?

Comment: I wanted to understand how to do both

Comment: When adding to an array you either use `arrayVar.push(newVal) ` or something more complicated like `arrayVar[arrayVar.length] = newVal;`. I think `.push` is much easier to understand and to write.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I can't believe so many people down voted this due to a lack of knowledge. How can  new people learn  to code if there scared  of asking the wrong question...I can even move discussion to a chat

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is fill in the age array with a loop, you can try this:

```js
let years = [2010, 2000, 1992],
  age = [],
  d = new Date().getFullYear();

years.forEach(year => age.push(d - year));
console.log(age);
```

As regards the relationship between age and names, I think Intervalia has explained that.

Answer (score 0):

A working version.
Please compare it with your code to see the differences. Arrays always got me when I was starting out, and the syntax with different across languages, despite the reuse of bracket symbols.. AutoIt language still trips me up :P

```
var names = ["Ace", "yoshi", "Lassie"];
var age = [25, 23, 5];
//Use array.push() to append values
var u24 = [];

//variable i counts up to names.length
//because i++ means 'add one' to i

for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    //if ([age] < 24) {u24 += age[i];
    //age at the count 'i' (which is
    //counting)
    //is achieved by array[at_index]
    if (age[i] < 24) {
        u24.push(age[i]); //add it to the end
        console.log("Hello " + names[i] +
          ", you are " + age[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very helpful as well thank you very much. I'm still in my first month of learn javascript so every bit of info helps.

Comment: No problemo bro, we've all been there! There isn't anything wrong with asking questions, so don't let the grump down votes get you :P

Comment: I know it's just hard enough having self teaching, then you come here and have people make you feel slow for asking a question.The html and css was easy but this stuff is a bit more difficult